# PXRedirect from BAccount -> new SOOrder, receiving error

Tags: acumatica

So I added the action to create new Sales Order with the current BAccount.BAccountID and I'm receiving this error "Value cannot be Null. Parameter name:key". Can anyone see specifically what I'm doing incorrectly? I was under the assumption that customerID and BAccountID were equivalent since they held the same values for IDs.

```
 public PXAction<BAccount> KSSOOrderPush;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create New Sales Order", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    protected virtual void kSSOOrderPush()
    {
        //Must use Base.BAccount.Current INSTEAD of BAccount.Current
        BAccount bacct = Base.BAccount.Current;
        if (bacct == null || bacct.BAccountID == null) return;

        //Create instance of graph
        SO.SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SO.SOOrderEntry>();


        graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<SOOrder.customerID>(bacct.BAccountID);


        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Sales Order");


    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're right - `SOOrder.CustomerID` takes the same values as `BAccount.BAccountID`. There is one important note here though: Business Accounts represent not only customers but also vendors, employees, etc., while it is possible to create Sales Orders (as well as AR documents) only for customers - keep this in mind and be sure to check that you're dealing with a customer when in this action (there is a type field on the `BAccount` class - checking it will be enough).

The problem with your code is that you don't actually create a Sales Order for the selected customer, but try to find one that belongs to this customer and navigate to it.

To create the order you should change the following line

```
graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<SOOrder.customerID(bacct.BAccountID);
```

to

```
// insert an SOOrder with default type
SOOrder newOrder = graph.Document.Insert();
// set appropriate CustomerID and update the order
newOrder.CustomerID = bacct.BAccountID;
graph.Document.Update(newOrder);
```

With these modifications `PXRedirectionException` should open the Sales Orders screen with Customer set to the one that you were seeing at the Business Accounts screen.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you for pointing out the error, I would have never guessed. The solution you proposed worked flawlessly!